# Mocking property depending on HttpRequest

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm having the following setup:

```
public class ExampleBaseController : Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controller
{
    public UserDetails UserDetails => Request.GetUserDetailsFromHttpHeaders();
}


public class ExampleConcreteController : ExampleBaseController
{
    // UserDetails is being used in here
    // this is the class under test
```

I need to be able to inject UserDetails during production run and also be able to mock it during tests.
Since UserDetails depends on Request and Request is a member of Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controller I do not know how to achieve this.

Comment: @eocron but how? I can't make an interface out of `ExampleBaseController ` and inject it in `ExampleConcreteController `. Could you explain what you mean?

Comment: @eocron can you provide an answer? It is not clear to me what you mean.
Also I think that the issue I am having is the fact that UserDetails can be accessed via inheritance instead of being injected inside ExampleConcreteController.

Comment: You can not inject UserDetails now because it is a property with getter only, as I understood.

Comment: @RăzvanFlaviusPanda I started writing up and answer only to realize that it ended up looking like the linked duplicate.

Comment: @Nkosi You do realise that: `Mocking property depending on HttpRequest` and `Mock HttpRequest` are different questions right? I'm really glad someone provided a good answer before the damage was done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to mock **something**, you should first **allow mocking** on it. If you want to mock UserDetails you should allow mocking on its getter and pass required context inside newly crafted contract:

```
public class ExampleBaseController : Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controller
{
    private readonly IUserDetailsProvider _userDetailsProvider;
    public UserDetails UserDetails => _userDetailsProvider.Get(Request);

    public ExampleBaseController(IUserDetailsProvider userDetailsProvider)
    {
        _userDetailsProvider = userDetailsProvider;
    }
}
```

So, in test you mock `IUserDetailsProvider` to return some "foobar". In production you just invoking `GetUserDetailsFromHttpHeaders()` method on passed inside `Request`.

To answer question about Request and Controller relations. Controller depends on Request, yes, and Microsoft thought that it will be good to strongly merge them together instead of passing dependency, for example like this:

```
public class FooBarController : Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controller
{
    private readonly System.Web.HttpRequestBase _request;

    public FooBarController(System.Web.HttpRequestBase request)
    {
        _request = request;
    }
}
```

Or even like this:

```
public class FooBarController : Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controller
{
    public void ProcessRequest(System.Web.HttpRequestBase request)
    {
        //request here
    }
}
```

They instead used Property injection, which leaves developer with no way to affect injection. This is a problem. But not unsolvable - you just pass context inside (by delegate, by interface, by reference), if you need one of those coupled together objects.

Comment: Wouldn't be better if UserDetail provider to be just Func<UserDetails> ? That way you can provide UserDetails stub and use labmda.

Comment: I suppose the only problem here will be to use `Request`´as UserDetailsProvider, because it will be property of the class itself.

Comment: @Belurd, It is minimal required and captured context for execution of 'GetUserDetailsFromHttpHeaders', without passing it inside, it would not be possible to retrieve UserDetails on normal execution.

Comment: Yes, I do not understand how this helps mocking since `UserDetails` depends on `Request`. I'd need a full example of how the injection of this would work in ExampleConcreteController .

Comment: ExampleBaseController depends on Request simply because it does not exist without one. Microsoft just has bad design patterns. It should have been injected in IUserDetailsProvider or provided as unit-of-work for controller, but life happens, it will not be injected and either you hack it by passing entire controller (which is cyclic dependency) or just Request which can't be injected other way around. You can inherit from it, facade it, but it will still be cyclic dependency because of bad coupling of controller pattern itself.

Answer (score 0):

It could be not so convinient as solution, proposed by @eocron, but still:

```
public interface IWithUserDetails
{
    UserDetails UserDetails();
}

public class ExampleBaseController : Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controller, IWithUserDetails
{
    public UserDetails UserDetails()
    {
        return Request.GetUserDetailsFromHttpHeaders();
    }
}
```

Same name for class and method is not a best way to do, but it was like it in the example with a property

Answer (score 0):

Here is another point of view:

```
public interface IUserDetailsProviderOptions
{
    Func<UserDetails> UserDetailsProvider { get; set; }
}

public class DefaultUserDetailsProviderOptions : IUserDetailsProviderOptions
{
    public Func<UserDetails> UserDetailsProvider {get; set;}
}

public class ExampleBaseController : Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controller
{
    private readonly Func<UserDetails> _userDetailsProvider;
    public UserDetails UserDetails => _userDetailsProvider();

    public ExampleBaseController(IUserDetailsProviderOptions options)
    {
         _userDetailsProvider = options.UserDetailsProvider ??
                              Request.GetUserDetailsFromHttpHeaders;
    }
}
```

Register in Startup.cs like this:

```
services.AddSingleton<IUserDetailsProviderOptions, DefaultUserDetailsProviderOptions>();
```

In testing you could do:

```
public class StubUserDetailsOption : IUserDetailsProviderOptions
{
    public Func<UserDetails> UserDetailsProvider { get; set; } = () => new StubDetails();
}

var controller = new ExampleBaseController(new StubUserDetailsOption());
```

and do testing.